# Edit the code snippet for generating methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

I'm trying to edit the template for generating methods in visual studio. I often type in a method name, then hit ctrl + . to generate it, like explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-method?view=vs-2019

I am trying to edit the template so it doesn't add

throw new NotImplementedException();

which is pretty annoying in unity since it adds using.system which can conflict with other stuff.

I've found a way to edit code snippets by locating them in this folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring,

but I can't find the right one for "Generate Method". Any help?
Thanks